# How can I access to app log in a Tizen app on a real Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I am running an App with Tizen on a Samsung Smart TV. The App is working fine on the emulator **Samsung Tizen TV Web Simulator** but when I run it on a Samsung TV there are some functions that are no working: for example, the red key "A", or the green key "B" and so on... and I can´t find a way to debug the error

My question is: Can I access to the log console when I run the app on the real Samsung Device?

On the Tizen App I write some "console.log()" to have some Javascript log, and I can read this log when I am working the Tizen emulator, but I don´t know how to read this log when the app is running on the Samsung TV...

I am using Tizen SDK 2.4 and the Samsung Smart TV model is UN48JU6500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is:

- **Yes**: If you are using the IDE/debugger with the actual device. See [How to install and run App in the TV](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3511/index.html#How-to-run/debug-App-using-SDK-IDE) for details about putting the TV into "Developer Mode" and attaching the debugger.
- **No**: If you launched the app directly on the TV (i.e., not from the debugger).  You do not have access to internal console on the device.  If you want a solution to capturing logging information in a true "production" setting, see some of the suggestions I laid out in [Not getting proper logs in Samsung Tizen TV emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827927/not-getting-proper-logs-in-samsung-tizen-tv-emulator/37845599#37845599)

If you need additional help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks +davesaus, the solution using "Developer Mode" on TV and attaching the debugger was what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you explain how to receive console logs from Samsung smart TV non Tizen version ?

Comment: @user1788736 Hi were you able to get these logs, I am stuck in this situation for past one month and no help received from samsung..