# console.log not work in Samsung Tizen TV Emulator (web app)

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-tv

I am trying to debug my web app with Tizen IDE + Emulator, but console does not work. When I run my app with the 'Debug as...' option it launches the app and the inspector opens correctly but the console tab is empty and I cannot run any JavaScript command in the console (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845599/3199735). Console output in the IDE is also empty. I tested this with the Basic TV app template, so there is no JavaScript code which disables console. I also tested the 'sdb dlog' command, but it just gives me an error.

I'm using the latest SDK and IDE.

Mac OSX 10.11.6
Tizen SDK

Version : 2.4.0_Rev8

[You can find same posts with screenshots from Samsung's forums](https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/9d322f0f492a38d7?forumID=09d313f369f5509e&currentPage=1&searchText=&selectcontents=1&selectPageSize=10&sorting_target=&sorting_type=desc)

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Tizen TV SDK provides [Web Inspector as debugging tool.](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen1251/index.html) Google chrome is required to be installed to perform such debug Operation. You can check the functionalities provided in [this document](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

a) Run the tizen project using Debug As-> Tizen Web Application. When you will debug the project on emulator, the Web Inspector (Debugging tool for Tizen SDK) will open in a separate window.

b) Go to the Source tab and enable Debugging :

[image]

c) You can also set breakpoints and debug stepping into line of codes. Click on the bottom tab to see the console. You can also check the console from console tab and also the IDE.

[image]

[image]

Otherwise, You can also Run As > Tizen Web Simulator Application (Samsung TV)
Then Click on the Inspect Icon & check the console tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didn't help. I enabled debugging from sources tab but console.log is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to create your own logger area in your app and list what is printed using a custom log function :\